# Multi-trip travel salesman problem

Tags: complexity-theory, graphs, combinatorics

Given a graph $G$, I want to find a shortest tour visiting each vertex. Different to the classical formulation of TSP, my tour needs to be divided into several subtours, each upper-bounded by a certain length. We can imagine that the salesman needs to return to the starting point to refill its car. The problem is to find the globally shortest TSP tour. Is there any TSP variant that is related to my formulation? My problem is clearly NP-hard, I'd like to design constant-factor approximate algorithm approaching the optimum.

Comment: How about first trying to 'split' the vertices into potential subtours and then solving TSP with an approximation algo on those subtours? Why would this or wouldn't this work in your case?

Comment: What variant of the TSP is this?  Is it metric TSP, Euclidean TSP, etc.?  Or fully general TSP? Approximability depends on which variant of TSP you have. What approaches have you considered?  There are many approximation algorithms for TSP.  Have you tried adapting any of them to your variant?  What have you found so far, when you tried that?  Have you made any progress?  Have you been able to prove that any of them do or don't work?

Comment: Thank you for your comments. I have found a related TSP variant of the above problem, the k-traveling salesperson problem.